# dependency on a non-existent parameter

Tags: symfony

I renamed a service from Notifications to Notification (Because I have already a class called Notifications), but when I tried to call it I have the following error:

> ParameterNotFoundException in ParameterBag.php line 106:
>   The service "notification" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "app.bundle.notification.class". Did you mean one of these: "app.bundle.utils.class", "app.bundle.notifications.class"?

In my Bundle/Services I have 2 files:
 - Notification.php
 - Utils.php

In Notification.php the class is called `class Notification {...}`

In my config file services.yml

```
notification:
    class:      %app.bundle.notification.class%
    arguments: [@templating]
```

I don't know where it can found the suggest value app.bundle.notification**s**.class

I tried to clear the cache but I have the same error.

Comment: What exactly have you changed? Is there a variable `app.bundle.notification.class` defined somewhere? Where and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare your service by this way:

```
parameters:
   your.service.class: ACME\YourBundle\Services\ServiceName

services:
     your.service:
          class: "%your.service.class%"
          arguments: [@templating]
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Symfony errors on container mistakes are - IMO - one of the best thing of this stack. Look closer:

`Did you mean one of these: "app.bundle.utils.class", "app.bundle.notifications.class"?`

Compiler tells you probable parameters you can use (and which exist). Check the ones of your bundle and rename this param to the new convention.

The simpliest thing to do: search whole project if it looks a bit `hidden`.

PS. Don't forget to delete cache.